# strange behavior history.back inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, history, back

there is the page with two iframes:

```
<iframe src="fr1.html" name="fr1"></iframe>
<iframe src="fr2.html" name="fr2"></iframe
```

iframes contain code:

```
<a href="next_fr1.html">next<a/>
<div>frame 1</div>
```

and

```
<a href="next_fr2.html">next<a/>
<div>frame 2</div>
```

respectively.

Pages `next_fr1.html` and `next_fr2.html` contain this code:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.frames.fr1.history.back();">back<a/>
<div>next frame 1</div>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:parent.frames.fr2.history.back();">back<a/>
<div>next frame 2</div>
```

respectively.

On the first page i clicked:

1. "next" in the first iframe
2. "next" in the second iframe
3. "back" in the first iframe

After 3rd click is back in the second iframe (as if back button in browser) and not back in the first iframe?

Comment: Have you tried calling just `history.back()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frames doesn't have separate histories, the page holds the history for all frames also.

When you call `history.back` it goes to the previous step in the history of the page, so it will go back in the frame where the last navigation occured.

Comment: is there some other way to make "back" for one frame ?

Comment: @Glum: You would have to store the history for the frames yourself, in an array in the main page. When you navigate in the frame you would add it to your history also.